# PROCESSENTRY32 .dwSize and sizeof

Tags: c++, size, byte

I read these two explanations of what each of these "functions" do, and while it looks like they are the same, they don't output the same value:

dwSize:

"The size of the structure, in bytes."

sizeof:

"sizeof(x) returns the amount of memory (in bytes) that the variable or type x occupies"

My code:

```
PROCESSENTRY32 entry;
cout >> entry.dwSize >> endl;
cout >> sizeof(entry) >> endl;
```

Why do `entry.dwSize` and `sizeof(entry)` not result in the same value when they're printed? According to the descriptions above, they should both give me the size of the entry in bytes.

Comment: Provide a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) please. Otherwise it's not possible to diagnose your actual problems beyond guessing. No clue why that question was upvoted. I' m just out of downvotes today to counter.

Comment: I changed the explanation, and there is no code, only the part of understanding is hard for me. that's because when I see the definitions of them both, they both give you the number of memory the struct takes in bytes, but they aren't the same

Answer (score 0):

From the [MSDN Documentation for PROCESSENTRY32](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684839(v=vs.85).aspx):

> dwSize
>   The size of the structure, in bytes. Before calling the Process32First function, set this member to sizeof(PROCESSENTRY32). If you do not initialize dwSize, Process32First fails.

So `dwSize` should be equal to `sizeof(PROCESSENTRY32)`, but creating a `struct` does not initialize its members, so there will be garbage in all of them until you set them.

Answer (score 0):

When you create a structure, it is either initialized with 0 bytes vor random. When you look at the [docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/windows/desktop/ms684839(v=vs.85).aspx), you will see that you have to fill dwSize yourself before using it.

Answer (score 0):

You confused two completely unrelated things. `PROCESSENTRY32::dwSize` is a data field that *you* are supposed to initialize to the size of the recipient `PROCESSENTRY32` struct. It is your responsibility to set it to the proper value. It won't magically set itself.

I.e. you are supposed to do

```
PROCESSENTRY32 entry;
entry.dwSize = sizeof entry;
...
```

before trying to pass `entry` to any WinAPI functions.

That's what the doc means when it ways that `dwSize` is "The size of the structure, in bytes".